# How to partially extract items in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

`l = [[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]],[[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24]]]]`

`l1=l[0][0][0]` (i.e. `[1, 2, 3]`)

`l2=l[0][1][0]` (i.e. `[7, 8, 9]`)

Is there a quicker way to obtain a list of `[[1, 2, 3],[7, 8, 9]]` in one go, without reshuffling the original list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. unpack to get get your wanted lists then put them together in a list

   ```
   [[x, _], [y, _]] = l[0]

   print([x, y])
   ```

   **output:**

   ```
   [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
   ```
2. use `next` and `zip` built-in functions:

   ```
   print(list(next(zip(*l[0]))))
   ```

   **output:**

   ```
   [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
   ```